# Use customized markers in FastMarkerCluster in Python folium?

Tags: python-3.x, folium

I'm able to add data to a folium map using MarkerCluster and vary the parameters of the marker according to parameters for each point.

```
###Toy Example 1###


import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import folium
import folium.plugins as plugins

lats = np.asarray([-54.4, -54.5, -54.6])
longs = np.asarray([-69.5, -69.5, -69.5])
data = np.asarray([70, 90, 5])
colour = np.asarray(['green', 'orange', 'red'])

dummy = [list(a) for a in zip(lats, longs, data, colour)]

dummy2 = pd.DataFrame(dummy, columns=['lat', 'lng', 'data', 'colour'])

dmap = folium.Map(location = [-54.5, -69.5], zoom_start = 7)

mc=plugins.MarkerCluster()

for a, row in dummy2.iterrows():
    folium.CircleMarker(location=[row[0],row[1]],
                        radius=row[2], color=row[3], fill=True).add_to(mc)

mc.add_to(dmap)

dmap
```

As my use case has thousands of points, I would like to do something similar to the above with FastMarkerCluster.  The farthest I've gone to achieving this is is:

```
###Toy Example 2###

callback = """\
function (row) {
    var marker;
    marker = L.circle(new L.LatLng(row[0], row[1]), {color:'red'});
    return marker;
};
"""

lats = np.asarray([-54.4, -54.5, -54.6])
longs = np.asarray([-69.5, -69.5, -69.5])
data = np.asarray([70, 90, 5])
colour = np.asarray(['green', 'orange', 'red'])

dummy = [list(a) for a in zip(lats, longs)]

dummy2 = pd.DataFrame(dummy, columns=['lat', 'lng'])

dmap = folium.Map(location = [-54.5, -69.5], zoom_start = 7)

plugins.FastMarkerCluster(dummy, callback=callback).add_to(dmap)

dmap
```

I can envision adding `{radius: row[2], color: row[3]}` to the callback to get the functionality I want.  However, if I add the `data` and/or `colour` arrays to `dummy` (as in Toy Example 1), I get `TypeError: must be real number, not numpy.str_`.  If I use `dummy2` in Toy Example 2, I get `TypeError: must be real number, not str`.

Any help on this is greatly appreciated.
f
Cheers,
-R

Comment: Making progress, slowly.  Apparently folium is reading the dataframe headers as part of the data, which is why I get TypeErrors that I do.  As per @Conegmo's suggestion [here](https://github.com/python-visualization/folium/issues/1089), converting the Pandas dataframe to a Numpy array gets around this issue as long as all the data is numeric.  Passing it any non-numeric data (e.g. 'colour' in my examples), gives a TypeError.

Comment: Good to hear that you're making progress and that Conegmo is open to making a change.  This will make a nice addition to folium

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is now solved in the Folium master branch on github thanks to Conegmo over there.  There had been an issue where the column names were being read as part of the data.  At the moment, installing Folium using the following means that all of the dummy examples I posted will work.

```
pip install git+https://github.com/python-visualization/folium.git
```